# React Hook State not matching

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I created a custom hook that monitors scrolling behavior. But when I change the state from the component that uses the hook, I do see the status change from console log but once I start scrolling the status has the original value of true. What is more strange is that the react dev tools does not match what console log output.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import useExample from './useExample';


function Example() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useExample();
  console.log(`example, status: ${status}`);


  useEffect(() => {
    setStatus(false);
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => console.log(status), 2000);
  }, [])

  return (<div>
    Something scrollable
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
  </div>);

}

export default Example;
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useExample = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(true);
  console.log(`useExample status: ${status}`);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  function handleScroll() {
    console.log(`handle scroll, status: ${status}`);
  }

  return [status, setStatus];
};

export default useExample;
```

I updated the function. The setInterval function always returns true, even though the status was changed in the first useEffect in Example.js.
[React dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkKBU.png)
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAuqV.png)

*Update* it works if I change it to this, I believe the issue has to do with the event listeners scope of status. It needs to be removed and updated with the correct state.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCa } from 'react';

const useExample = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(true);
  console.log(`useExample status: ${status}`);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, [status]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`${status} useffect`);
  }, [status]);

  function handleScroll() {
    console.log(`handle scroll, status: ${status}`);
  }

  return [status, setStatus];
};

export default useExample;
```

Comment: Why do you write the event listener în another component and not in the same component.

Comment: need to reuse the component

Answer (score 0):

you did not properly export your function in the example but you import them on the parent component, you use useState on the child component, if you want to separate the function as a child component the state should be in the parent component and import it in the the child where your status is set to initially to true, your useExample will always return true.

```
export const useExample = (status) => {

  console.log(`useExample status: ${status}`);

  function handleScroll() {
    console.log(`handle scroll, status: ${status}`);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
     return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

};
```

and in the parent it should be

```
import {useExample} from './useExample';

useExample(status);
```

but since what's inside the function is a useEffect then you can write it like this inside your parent component. It would be easier to do it this way.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
   const [status, setStatus] = useState(true);


   function handleScroll() {
     console.log(`handle scroll, status: ${status}`);
   }

   useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
     return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
   }, []);


   useEffect(() => {
     setStatus(false);
   },[]);

   useEffect(() => {
     setInterval(() => console.log(status), 2000);
   }, [])

   return (<div>
     Something scrollable
      ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
   </div>);

}

export default Example;
```

Comment: but im returning [status, setStatus] not {status, setStatus} from useExample

Comment: I updated my answer, check if this will work. I haven't tested it though

Comment: hmm, not sure, so I saw the problem, I am using event listeners which need to be remounted if using hooks,

Comment: Also trying to resuse the scrolling logic so I need it in a separate hook